# which operator+ function is invoked when I add int to char ('a' + 1)

Tags: c++, casting, operators

I've following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << ('a' + 1) << endl;
  cout << static_cast<char>('a' + 1) << endl;
  cout << static_cast<int>('a' + 1) << endl;
}
```

> The output is:
>   98
>   b
>   98

I assume, that `'a' + 1` is computing with function `int operator+(int, int)` in following order:

1. 'a' is casted to int
2. `operator+` returns integer result (98)

It all are my predictions. How can I check which function is invoked to be 100% sure?

### Update

More clear type revision:

```
  cout << (typeid('a') == typeid(char) ? "char" : "not char") << endl;
  cout << (typeid(1) == typeid(int) ? "int" : "not int") << endl;
  cout << (typeid('a' + 1) == typeid(int) ? "int" : "not int") << endl;
```

> The output is:
>   char
>   int
>   int

Comment: `char` can't have a constructor because it's not a class. And if you want to go from `int` to `char`, use `static_cast` or just store the result in a `char`.

Comment: so how `char a = 97;` works?

Comment: int i = reinterpret_cast<int>(ret);
don't work too...

Comment: you must be getting 'b' as the output right?

Comment: The cast from `char` to `int` is static.

Comment: Because `a` is an integer type the rhs is value-promoted and saved. Not sure what the mystery is here, but maybe I missed something. that cast should be static-only.

Comment: @Brian
what does it exactly mean?

Comment: What exactly is your question? And why are you obsessed with `reinterpret_cast`? In the expression `'a' + 1`, `'a'` undergoes *integral promotion*, addition is performed, and the result is converted to `char` because you're storing the result in a `char`.

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk, `reinterpret_cast` doesn't work because it's not a pointer or reference. `reinterpret_cast` is a last resort, though.

Comment: Read C++11 § 4.5 [conv.prom]. And maybe C++11 § 5.2.10, [expr.reinterpret.cast] while you're there.

Comment: sorry, I deceive reinterpret with static cast...
But question is still the same.
Am i right that `int operator+(int, int)` is invoked? How can i check it?

Comment: I updated my question with more clear example (no mistake with reinterpret cast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Built-in operators form basic expressions which are *not* function calls. They are part of the core language. For arithmetic types, there's a set of conversions (the "usual arithmetic conversions", 5/9) that's applied so that both operands are values of the same type. In your example, one operand is `char` and the other `int`, so the `char` is promoted to an `int` or `unsigned int` by the integral promotion rules, and then an appropriate conversion is applied to the other operand. (Typically, both sides would end up as an `int`, though you can contrive platforms where it would be `unsigned int`.)

Comment: They are not function calls, but they participate in overload selection according to the rules for function calls.